# Can I use different font sizes in the title of my document?

Tags: document-classes, small-caps, posters, options

I am using a poster template I found [here](https://nl.overleaf.com/latex/templates/dtu-poster/nfchvswyhcnq) to base my poster on. I want to use small caps in my title, but the font used, `cmbright`, does not support this.

So I thought I could fake it by doing something like this:

```
S\footnotesize{MALL}\normalsize{C}\footnotesize{APS}
```

which works in the running text and in the section headers (using `\protect`), but not in the `title` option of the `documentclass`. When I use it there, the code does not compile, and I get the following error (at the command `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`):

```
Undefined control sequence. \usepackage
```

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[
    ,title     = {{S\footnotesize{MALL}\normalsize{C}\footnotesize{APS}: No small caps}}
    ,toplogo   = {{uni-logo}}
    ,papersize = {{a0paper}}
    ,colcount  = {{3columns}}
    ,longtitle
    ,nocrop
]{dtuposter}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % special characters
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    % Unicode, Linux

\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage{arevmath}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nosep,leftmargin=*}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
```

My question: How can I use `\normalsize`, `\footnotesize` etc. in the `documentclass` `title` option? Is there some workaround that does not include fiddling with the `dtuposter.cls` file?

Unfortunately, I can't provide a MWE because for the code to run, the `dtuposter.cls` file and some other files and images are required - and I can't attach these here.

I am on Windows and use MiKTeX 2.9.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest a different strategy:

```latex
\documentclass[
  title = SMALLCAPS: Small caps,
  toplogo = uni-logo,
  papersize = a0paper,
  colcount  = 3columns,
  longtitle,
  nocrop,
]{dtuposter}

\makeatletter
\protected\def\rdvtitle{%
  \check@mathfonts
  S{\fontsize{\sf@size}{0}\selectfont MALL}C{\fontsize{\sf@size}{0}\selectfont APS}:
  Small caps%
}
\makeatother
\setkeys{dtuposter}{title=\rdvtitle}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % special characters
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    % Unicode, Linux

\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage{arevmath}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nosep,leftmargin=*}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Note that `\footnotesize` is wrong, because the title is typeset at in a larger font; with `\sf@size` we get the size for first level subscripts in the current font size.

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! This works. However, I get an error message pertaining to the `geometry.sty` file : `Missing \endcsname inserted. \ProcessOptionsKV[c]{Gm}`, as well as a warning pertaining to the `main.tex` file: `Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref) removing \rdvtitle`. Also, the spacing between the two lines that the title consists of has reduced now. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @rdv I found a better way, see edited answer

Comment: Thanks again - no more error messages! Can you also advise on the issue that my two-line title is now too narrowly spaced? I tried `\setkeys{dtuposter}{title=\rdvtitle\par}` (so adding `\par`) - but this spreads the lines too much, pushing the content of the poster to a second page.

Comment: @rdv Sorry, but I can't see “too large or too narrow spreading”.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. In the example above there is no problem since the whole title is on one line. My actual title, however, is much longer and needs two lines - and there is very little spacing between them, giving a cramped look.

Comment: @rdv I tried with a very long title.